# Unable to install jade in a node.js project

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, pug

I am trying a sample node.js based project by referring this tutorial: [How To Write A Simple Node.js/MongoDB Web Service for an iOS App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/61078/write-simple-node-jsmongodb-web-service-ios-app). I have configured my package.json like this:

```
{
    "name": "mango-server",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "*",
        "jade": "*"
    }
}
```

Problem is - when I try `npm update` or `npm install` it is showing me below error messages on console:

```
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: uglify-js@'^2.4.19'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.0.1","0.0.2","0.0.3","0.0.4","0.0.5","1.0.1","1.0.2","1.0.3","1.0.4","1.0.5","1.0.6","1.0.7","1.1.0","1.1.1","1.2.0","1.2.1","1.2.2","1.2.3","1.2.4","1.2.5","1.2.6","1.3.0","1.3.1","1.3.2","1.3.3","1.3.4","2.2.0","2.2.1","2.2.2","2.2.3","2.2.4","2.2.5","2.3.0","2.3.1","2.3.2","2.3.3","2.3.4","2.3.5","2.3.6","1.3.5","2.4.0","2.4.1","2.4.2","2.4.3","2.4.4","2.4.5","2.4.6","2.4.7","2.4.8","2.4.9","2.4.10","2.4.11","2.4.12","2.4.13","2.4.14","2.4.15","2.4.16","2.4.17","2.4.18","2.4.19","2.4.20","2.4.21","2.4.22","2.4.23"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:685:10)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:607:10
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:138:7)
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "update"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/devarshi/Documents/NodeTutorial
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.3
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.17
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/constantinople
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jstransformer/0.0.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/character-parser/1.2.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/with
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/clean-css
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/void-elements
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/transformers/2.1.0
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/devarshi/Documents/NodeTutorial/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I am clueless, please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a non supported npm and an old nodejs version, please upgrade node (npm is embedded) ans try again.
https://nodejs.org/download/

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer, I got it working by upgrading the npm :)